# how to use android imsevice port

Tags: android, message, serversocket

i am building a chat application for android i want to use socket as a method of transfering message i used this tutorial but i found out that the messaging works only when both phones are on the same network .so i made some research and i want to use this imservice tutorial https://github.com/Pirngruber/AndroidIM. and i and just want to know how to send message from one phone to another... .i want a case where by i insert the message, port and ip. into different edittext and it locates the other phone with the ip and the person would see the message in the sever side of the app already installed. How do i do that.

this is the imsevice.java class i found

```
 package com.ex.da;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;




public class IMService extends Service  {


    public static String USERNAME;
    public static final String TAKE_MESSAGE = "Take_Message";
    public static final String FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Friend List";
    public static final String MESSAGE_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Message List";
    public ConnectivityManager conManager = null; 
    private final int UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD = 15000;
//  private static final INT LISTENING_PORT_NO = 8956;
    private String rawFriendList = new String();
    private String rawMessageList = new String();

    ISocketOperator socketOperator = new SocketOperator(this);

    private final IBinder mBinder = new IMBinder();
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean authenticatedUser = false;
     // timer to take the updated data from server
    private Timer timer;


    private LocalStorageHandler localstoragehandler; 

    private NotificationManager mNM;

    public class IMBinder extends Binder {
        public IAppManager getService() {
            return IMService.this;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {       
         mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

         localstoragehandler = new LocalStorageHandler(this);
        // Display a notification about us starting.  We put an icon in the status bar.
     //   showNotification();
        conManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        new LocalStorageHandler(this);

        // Timer is used to take the friendList info every UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD;
        timer = new Timer();   

        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {         

                //socketOperator.startListening(LISTENING_PORT_NO);
                Random random = new Random();
                int tryCount = 0;
                while (socketOperator.startListening(10000 + random.nextInt(20000))  == 0 )
                {       
                    tryCount++; 
                    if (tryCount > 10)
                    {
                        // if it can't listen a port after trying 10 times, give up...
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        };      
        thread.start();

    }

/*
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Cancel the persistent notification.
        mNM.cancel(R.string.local_service_started);

        // Tell the user we stopped.
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.local_service_stopped, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
*/  

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return mBinder;
    }




    /**
     * Show a notification while this service is running.
     * @param msg 
     **/
    private void showNotification(String username, String msg) 
    {       
        // Set the icon, scrolling text and TIMESTAMP
        String title = "AndroidIM: You got a new Message! (" + username + ")";

        String text = username + ": " + 
                    ((msg.length() < 5) ? msg : msg.substring(0, 5)+ "...");

        //NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(R.drawable.stat_sample, title,System.currentTimeMillis());
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.stat_sample)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text); 



        Intent i = new Intent(this, Messaging.class);
        i.putExtra(FriendInfo.USERNAME, username);
        i.putExtra(MessageInfo.MESSAGETEXT, msg);   

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                i, 0);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        // msg.length()>15 ? MSG : msg.substring(0, 15);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent); 

        mBuilder.setContentText("New message from " + username + ": " + msg);

        //TODO: it can be improved, for instance message coming from same user may be concatenated 
        // next version

        // Send the notification.
        // We use a layout id because it is a unique number.  We use it later to cancel.
        mNM.notify((username+msg).hashCode(), mBuilder.build());
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }


    public String sendMessage(String  username, String  tousername, String message) throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
    {           
        String params = "username="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.username,"UTF-8") +
                        "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.password,"UTF-8") +
                        "&to=" + URLEncoder.encode(tousername,"UTF-8") +
                        "&message="+ URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8") +
                        "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("sendMessage","UTF-8")+
                        "&";        
        Log.i("PARAMS", params);
        return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);      
    }


    private String getFriendList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException  {       
        // after authentication, server replies with friendList xml

         rawFriendList = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
         if (rawFriendList != null) {
             this.parseFriendInfo(rawFriendList);
         }
         return rawFriendList;
    }

    private String getMessageList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException     {       
        // after authentication, server replies with friendList xml

         rawMessageList = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
         if (rawMessageList != null) {
             this.parseMessageInfo(rawMessageList);
         }
         return rawMessageList;
    }

    public String authenticateUser(String usernameText, String passwordText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
    {
        this.username = usernameText;
        this.password = passwordText;   

        this.authenticatedUser = false;

        String result = this.getFriendList(); //socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
        if (result != null && !result.equals(Login.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)) 
        {           
            // if user is authenticated then return string from server is not equal to AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
            this.authenticatedUser = true;
            rawFriendList = result;
            USERNAME = this.username;
            Intent i = new Intent(FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED);                 
            i.putExtra(FriendInfo.FRIEND_LIST, rawFriendList);
            sendBroadcast(i);

            timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
            {           
                public void run() 
                {
                    try {                   
                        //rawFriendList = IMService.this.getFriendList();
                        // sending friend list 
                        Intent i = new Intent(FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED);
                        Intent i2 = new Intent(MESSAGE_LIST_UPDATED);
                        String tmp = IMService.this.getFriendList();
                        String tmp2 = IMService.this.getMessageList();
                        if (tmp != null) {
                            i.putExtra(FriendInfo.FRIEND_LIST, tmp);
                            sendBroadcast(i);   
                            Log.i("friend list broadcast sent ", "");

                        if (tmp2 != null) {
                            i2.putExtra(MessageInfo.MESSAGE_LIST, tmp2);
                            sendBroadcast(i2);  
                            Log.i("friend list broadcast sent ", "");
                        }
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.i("friend list returned null", "");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                   
                }           
            }, UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD, UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD);
        }

        return result;      
    }

    public void messageReceived(String username, String message) 
    {               

        //FriendInfo friend = FriendController.getFriendInfo(username);
        MessageInfo msg = MessageController.checkMessage(username);
        if ( msg != null)
        {           
            Intent i = new Intent(TAKE_MESSAGE);

            i.putExtra(MessageInfo.USERID, msg.userid);         
            i.putExtra(MessageInfo.MESSAGETEXT, msg.messagetext);           
            sendBroadcast(i);
            String activeFriend = FriendController.getActiveFriend();
            if (activeFriend == null || activeFriend.equals(username) == false) 
            {
                localstoragehandler.insert(username,this.getUsername(), message.toString());
                showNotification(username, message);
            }

            Log.i("TAKE_MESSAGE broadcast sent by im service", "");
        }   

    }  

    private String getAuthenticateUserParams(String usernameText, String passwordText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
    {           
        String params = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(usernameText,"UTF-8") +
                        "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(passwordText,"UTF-8") +
                        "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("authenticateUser","UTF-8")+
                        "&port="    + URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(socketOperator.getListeningPort()),"UTF-8") +
                        "&";        

        return params;      
    }

    public void setUserKey(String value) 
    {       
    }

    public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        return conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }

    public boolean isUserAuthenticated(){
        return authenticatedUser;
    }

    public String getLastRawFriendList() {      
        return this.rawFriendList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("IMService is being destroyed", "...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void exit() 
    {
        timer.cancel();
        socketOperator.exit(); 
        socketOperator = null;
        this.stopSelf();
    }

    public String signUpUser(String usernameText, String passwordText,
            String emailText) 
    {
        String params = "username=" + usernameText +
                        "&password=" + passwordText +
                        "&action=" + "signUpUser"+
                        "&email=" + emailText+
                        "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);     

        return result;
    }

    public String addNewFriendRequest(String friendUsername) 
    {
        String params = "username=" + this.username +
        "&password=" + this.password +
        "&action=" + "addNewFriend" +
        "&friendUserName=" + friendUsername +
        "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);     

        return result;
    }

    public String sendFriendsReqsResponse(String approvedFriendNames,
            String discardedFriendNames) 
    {
        String params = "username=" + this.username +
        "&password=" + this.password +
        "&action=" + "responseOfFriendReqs"+
        "&approvedFriends=" + approvedFriendNames +
        "&discardedFriends=" +discardedFriendNames +
        "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);     

        return result;

    } 

    private void parseFriendInfo(String xml)
    {           
        try 
        {
            SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            sp.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()), new XMLHandler(IMService.this));     
        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
    private void parseMessageInfo(String xml)
    {           
        try 
        {
            SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            sp.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()), new XMLHandler(IMService.this));     
        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

}
```

and this is the message class

```
package at.vcity.androidim;


import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import at.vcity.androidim.interfaces.IAppManager;
import at.vcity.androidim.services.IMService;
import at.vcity.androidim.tools.FriendController;
import at.vcity.androidim.tools.LocalStorageHandler;
import at.vcity.androidim.types.FriendInfo;
import at.vcity.androidim.types.MessageInfo;


public class Messaging extends Activity {

    private static final int MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT = 0;
    public String username;
    private EditText messageText;
    private EditText messageHistoryText;
    private Button sendMessageButton;
    private IAppManager imService;
    private FriendInfo friend = new FriendInfo();
    private LocalStorageHandler localstoragehandler; 
    private Cursor dbCursor;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {



        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {          
            imService = ((IMService.IMBinder)service).getService();
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            imService = null;
            Toast.makeText(Messaging.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

        setContentView(R.layout.messaging_screen); //messaging_screen);

        messageHistoryText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageHistory);

        messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);

        messageText.requestFocus();         

        sendMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessageButton);

        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();


        friend.userName = extras.getString(FriendInfo.USERNAME);
        friend.ip = extras.getString(FriendInfo.IP);
        friend.port = extras.getString(FriendInfo.PORT);
        String msg = extras.getString(MessageInfo.MESSAGETEXT);



        setTitle("Messaging with " + friend.userName);


    //  EditText friendUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.friendUserName);
    //  friendUserName.setText(friend.userName);


        localstoragehandler = new LocalStorageHandler(this);
        dbCursor = localstoragehandler.get(friend.userName, IMService.USERNAME );

        if (dbCursor.getCount() > 0){
        int noOfScorer = 0;
        dbCursor.moveToFirst();
            while ((!dbCursor.isAfterLast())&&noOfScorer<dbCursor.getCount()) 
            {
                noOfScorer++;

                this.appendToMessageHistory(dbCursor.getString(2) , dbCursor.getString(3));
                dbCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        localstoragehandler.close();

        if (msg != null) 
        {
            this.appendToMessageHistory(friend.userName , msg);
            ((NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).cancel((friend.userName+msg).hashCode());
        }

        sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            CharSequence message;
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                message = messageText.getText();
                if (message.length()>0) 
                {       
                    appendToMessageHistory(imService.getUsername(), message.toString());

                    localstoragehandler.insert(imService.getUsername(), friend.userName, message.toString());

                    messageText.setText("");
                    Thread thread = new Thread(){                   
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                if (imService.sendMessage(imService.getUsername(), friend.userName, message.toString()) == null)
                                {

                                    handler.post(new Runnable(){    

                                        public void run() {

                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.message_cannot_be_sent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                            //showDialog(MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT);                                       
                                        }

                                    });
                                }
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.message_cannot_be_sent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }                       
                    };
                    thread.start();

                }

            }});

        messageText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
            {
                if (keyCode == 66){
                    sendMessageButton.performClick();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }


        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        int message = -1;
        switch (id)
        {
        case MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT:
            message = R.string.message_cannot_be_sent;
        break;
        }

        if (message == -1)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(Messaging.this)       
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                }
            })        
            .create();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
        unbindService(mConnection);

        FriendController.setActiveFriend(null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {       
        super.onResume();
        bindService(new Intent(Messaging.this, IMService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
        i.addAction(IMService.TAKE_MESSAGE);

        registerReceiver(messageReceiver, i);

        FriendController.setActiveFriend(friend.userName);      


    }


    public class  MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {       
            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            String username = extra.getString(MessageInfo.USERID);          
            String message = extra.getString(MessageInfo.MESSAGETEXT);

            if (username != null && message != null)
            {
                if (friend.userName.equals(username)) {
                    appendToMessageHistory(username, message);
                    localstoragehandler.insert(username,imService.getUsername(), message);

                }
                else {
                    if (message.length() > 15) {
                        message = message.substring(0, 15);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Messaging.this,  username + " says '"+
                                                    message + "'",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
                }
            }           
        }

    };
    private MessageReceiver messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver();

    public  void appendToMessageHistory(String username, String message) {
        if (username != null && message != null) {
            messageHistoryText.append(username + ":\n");                                
            messageHistoryText.append(message + "\n");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (localstoragehandler != null) {
            localstoragehandler.close();
        }
        if (dbCursor != null) {
            dbCursor.close();
        }
    }


}
```